# PyDev Eclypse serial.tools library

Tags: python, eclipse, serial-port

I need to import serial library in my python project that uses PyQt to build user inteface.
To list all avcailable serial ports I tried to use this command:

```
 import serial
 ...
 def findComPorts(self):
    list=serial.tools.list_ports_osx.comports()
    port=serial.Serial('...',baudrate=38400)`
```

but eclipse shows the error: **Undefined variable from import: tools**

I also tried:

```
from serial import tools 
... 
def findComPorts(self):
    list=tools.list_ports_osx.comports()
    port=serial.Serial('...',baudrate=38400)
```

but now the error at runtime is: **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'list_ports_osx'**
I'm running Eclypse Kepler, Python 2.7, pySerial 2.7 installed via macports